# How can a value be accumulated when run in parallel/concurent processes?

Tags: ruby, selenium

I'm running some Ruby scripts concurrently using [Grosser/Parallel](https://github.com/grosser/parallel).

During each concurrent test I want to add up the number of times a particular thing has happened, then display that number.

Let's say:

```
def main
  $this_happened = 0
  do_this_in_parallel
  puts $this_happened
end

def do_this_in_parallel
  Parallel.each(...) { 
    $this_happened += 1
  }
end
```

The final value after `do_this_in_parallel` has finished will always be `0`

1. I'd like to know why this happens.
2. How can I get the desired result which would be `$this_happenend > 0`?

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, but I still can't seem to get a grip on it.

If I have a specific function that occurs under certain conditions inside each parallel execution, how do I get that specific count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't work because separate processes have separate memory spaces: setting variables etc in one process has no effect on what happens in the other process.

However you can return a result from your block (because under the hood parallel sets up pipes so that the processes can be fed input/return results). For example you could do this

```
counts = Parallel.map(...) do
   #the return value of the block should
   #be the number of times the event occurred
end
```

Then just sum the counts to get your total count (eg `counts.reduce(:+)`). You might also want to read up on map-reduce for more information about this way of parallelising work

Comment: Thanks @frederick-cheung however I don't completely understand where I put $this_happened += 1 so that I can use it later.

Comment: You don't - manipulating a global variable in your parallel processes is fundamentally flawed. Within the block calculate the contribution made by that process only.

Comment: I get you. I'm coming at this the wrong way. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I have never used `parallel` but the documentation seems to suggest that something like this might work.

```
Parallel.each(..., :finish => lambda {|*_| $this_happened += 1}) { do_work }
```

Comment: Thanks @engineersmnky - I see where you're going with this, but unfortunately I can't get this to work.

Comment: @YoDK No problem like I said haven't actually used it the docs just seemed to hint that this may be a possible solution